# Flask running script instead of just displaying passed values

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have a time-consuming python script I run from a Flask front end.  The results can be viewed in a number of ways by the user.  To save time, I pass back all possible results the first time the script is run.  The results page has 3 buttons to allow the user to just view the data in preferred format.
Unfortunately, each button click results in re-running of the script.

I pass the following to a python script, processSCTInput via flask :
1. Invoice file with material information, 
2. Trucks available to carry the given loads.

The script gives weight and volume utilisation and cost for different truck combinations. It considers both all Truck Types possible and all available. It sends the results back for AllTrucks and Available trucks as data frames.

To make it easier to understand the results, I give 3 buttons to limit results viewing:
1.  By all available trucks
2.  By best utilisation of all available trucks for each destination
3.  By best rate of all available trucks

```
@app.route('/processSCT', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def processSCT():
    allOutput,avlOutput,notInPFEP,noPUC=processSCTInput(session)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'avlTrucks' in request.form:
            print('Button Clicked for Customer')
            text="Truck Recommendation by Available Trucks"
            if session['AvailableTrucks']:
                df=avlOutput
            else:
                df=allOutput
                text="blah 1"
            return render_template('/resultsSCT.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data',header='true',index=False)],text=text)
        if 'bestWt' in request.form:
            print('Button Clicked')
            text="Best Trucks By Utilisation from available Trucks"
            if session['AvailableTrucks']:
                df=avlOutput
            else:
                df=allOutput
                text="blah 2"
            df.sort_values(by=['City','WtUtil%','VolUtil%','%Spend'],ascending=[True,False,False,True],inplace=True)
            df=df.drop_duplicates('City')

            return render_template('/resultsSCT.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data',header='true',index=False)],text=text)
        if 'bestRate' in request.form:
            print('Button Clicked')
            text="blah 3"
            if session['AvailableTrucks']:
                df=avlOutput
            else:
                df=allOutput
                text="blah 3"
            df.sort_values(by=['City','%Spend','WtUtil%','VolUtil%'],ascending=[True,True,False,False],inplace=True)
            df=df.drop_duplicates('City')
            return render_template('/resultsSCT.html', tables=[df.to_html(classes='data',header='true',index=False)],text=text)

        if 'Results' in request.form:
            print('Button Clicked')
        #return results
            return render_template('resultsSCT.html', tables=[allOutput.to_html(classes='data',header='true')])
    return render_template('/sct.html',tables=[allOutput.to_html(classes='data',header='true')] )
```

My expectation is the different buttons will use the 2 data frames, allOutput and avlOutput received in the first line.

```
<h3>Processing for All Trucks!</h3>
<br>
<br>





<form method="post" action="", novalidate>
    <br>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    </div><input class = "button" type="submit" name="avlTrucks" value="Available Trucks">
       <div class="divider"></div>
    <input class = "button" type="submit" name="bestWt" value="Available By Utilisation">
    <div class="divider">
    </div><input class = "button" type="submit" name="bestRate" value="Available By Rate">


                <br>
                </h3>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Results : {{text}}!</h3>
<table class="centered thick-border">
{% for table in tables %}
{{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</table>
<h3><a href="/downloadFiles">Download</a> displayed data as csv files.</h3>
<br>

{% endblock %}
```

Instead every button click results in the re-running of processSCTInput!

This is with python 3.7 and a virtualenv set up as per Miguel Grinberg tutorial.
I am a complete newbie to front end programming of any sort.  This is accomplished with the help of tutorials. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're submiting the form.

You should try use `ajaxCall` so when you click on some option you put an gif or js animation to load data then use `success`of ajax to display the information

Somelike the propuse:

```
function myReport(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/processSCT",
        data: { option: id},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data)
        }, 
        error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Something gots wrong, shit!')
        }
    });
}
```

And you should put id's on tables to edit specific one if you will show all of them

Comment: Thanks.  so far, I have not tried anything beyond basic python and flask.... If nothing else works, I will have to try other venues